# Pagina web para celular con Python flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Estoy intentando visualizar mi pagina web hecja en flask con python en mi celular, no me carga en mi celular coloco lo siguientes ipv4demicomputadora:5000

Código python:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import serial ,time
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3',9600)

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('Home.html')


@app.route('/leds',methods=["GET","POST"])
def leds():
    numero = request.form["prender"]
    arduino.write(numero.encode())
    return render_template('Home.html',nombre = numero)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Estoy haciendo una interfaz para controlar arduino por medio del serial, la verdad no se si sera posible verla en celular y pues localmente la ip es 127.0.0.1:5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `app.run()`

Agrega `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` o también puedes probar con:

`flask run --host=0.0.0.0`

Comment: Gracias me funciono!